# req.flash is not a function error

Tags: node.js, express, flash-message

below is my code for registering a user. after intalling the necessary modules. express-flash-2 and express-session. The code below gave me the error "req.flash is not a function". any way I can go about it?

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  var db = firebase.database();
  var email = req.body.email;
  var name = req.body.name;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  if(email === "" || name === "" || username === "" || password === "") {
    req.flash('msg', 'All fields are required.'); 
    res.redirect('/signup');
  } else {
    console.log('register successfully');
  }
```

});

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash
Please see if you have correctly implemented

Comment: I am using express 4 and connect-flash is not supported. however it has been  4 years since connect-flash is updated.

Comment: is it throwing you any error? I am using connect-flash with express 4.

Comment: alright, let me give it a try